# SFTP issue PAM drops session REDHAT

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, sftp

I'm currently troubleshooting a issue with a sftp server, users aren't able to log into the server and I don't see anything wrong with the sshd_config file. When users try to log into the service they get an authentication error and when I look at logs I see that pam drops the session.

[image: IMG:]

Any suggestions?

Pam log
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPr89.jpg)

Comment: Could you show the PAM logs?

Comment: i added the log that i get from one of the users